# R unable to detect that I have more than one column in loaded files

Tags: r

What I want to do is take every file in the subdirectory that I am in and essentially just shift the column header names over one left.

[image: Example of my data table]

I try to accomplish this by using `fread` in a for loop:

```
library(data.table)
## I need to write this script to reorder the column headers which are now apparently out of wack
## I just need to shift them over one
filelist <- list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")

for(i in 1:length(filelist)){
  assign(filelist[[i]], fread(filelist[[i]], fill = TRUE))
  names(filelist[[i]]) <- c("RowID", "rsID", "PosID", "Link", "Link.1","Direction", "Spearman_rho", "-log10(p)")
}
```

However, I keep getting the following or a variant of the following error message:

```
Error in names(filelist[[i]]) <- c("RowID", "rsID", "PosID", "Link", "Link.1",  : 
  'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

Which is confusing to me because, as you can clearly see above, R Studio is able to load the files as having the correct number of columns. However, the error message seems to imply that there is only one column. I have tried different functions, such as `colnames`, and I have even tried to define the separator as being quotation marks (as my files were previously generated by another R script that quotation-separated the entries), to no luck. In fact, if I try to define the separator as such:

```
for(i in 1:length(filelist)){
  assign(filelist[[i]], fread(filelist[[i]], sep = "\"", fill = TRUE))
  names(filelist[[i]]) <- c("RowID", "rsID", "PosID", "Link", "Link.1","Direction", "Spearman_rho", "-log10(p)")
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in fread(filelist[[i]], sep = "\"", fill = TRUE) : 
  sep == quote ('"') is not allowed
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that, despite the name, `list.files` returns a character vector, not a `list`. So using `[[` isn't right. Then, with `assign`, you create an objects that have the same name as the files (not good practice, it would be better to use a list). Then you try to modify the names of the object created, but only using the character string of the object name. To use an object who's name is in a character string, you need to use `get` (which is part of why using a `list` is better than creating a bunch of objects).

To be more explicit, let's say that `filelist = c("data1.txt", "data2.txt")`. Then, when `i = 1`, this code: `assign(filelist[[i]], fread(filelist[[i]], fill = TRUE))` creates a data table called `data1.txt`. But your next line, `names(filelist[[i]]) <- ...` doesn't modify your data table, it modifies the first element of `filelist`, which is the string `"data1.txt"`, and that string indeed has  length `1`.

I recommend reading your files into a list instead of using `assign` to create objects.

```
filelist <- list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")
datalist <- lapply(filelist, fread, fill = TRUE)
names(datalist) <- filelist
```

For changing the names, you can use `data.table::setnames` instead:

```
for(dt in datalist) setnames(dt, c("RowID", "rsID", "PosID", "Link", "Link.1","Direction", "Spearman_rho", "-log10(p)"))
```

However, `fread` has a `col.names` argument, so you can just do it in the read step directly:

```
my_names <- c("RowID", "rsID", "PosID", "Link", "Link.1","Direction", "Spearman_rho", "-log10(p)")
datalist <- lapply(filelist, fread, fill = TRUE, col.names = my_names)
```

I would also suggest **not** using `"-log10(p)"` as a column name - nonstandard column names (with parens and `-`) are usually more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. Question: how were you able to use `fread` without explicitly entering an `input` argument? Also, how were you able to enter other arguments without using parentheses?

Comment: That's what `lapply` does. `lapply(inputs, foo, bar = x, baz = y)` is a shortcut for `list(foo(inputs[1], bar = x, baz = y), foo(inputs[2], bar = x, baz = y), foo(inputs[3], bar = x, baz = y), ...)`. All arguments to `lapply` are passed on to whatever function is in the function argument.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run the following code to have a closer look at what you are putting into filelist?

```
i <- 1
assign(filelist[[i]], fread(filelist[[i]], fill = TRUE))
print(filelist[[i]])
```

I suspect you may need to use the code below instead of the assign statement

```
filelist[[i]] <- fread(filelist[[i]], fill = TRUE)
```